# Why does The Creeper sew dead bodies on the wall?

Tags: plot-explanation, jeepers-creepers

In *Jeepers Creepers (2001)*, Darry falls into a pipeline where earlier The Creeper is shown dropping bodies into it. The pipeline leads to a basement beneath a church. After falling into the pipeline, Darry heads further into the basement where he sees dead bodies sewn onto the wall by The Creeper.

**Why does The Creeper sew dead bodies onto the wall?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Because that's the Creeper's personality. It's not explained further than that.*

We find that Creeper needs to replenish body parts in order to continue on with his "return every 23 years" cycle. But we do know events that indicate his "feelings": (1) Creeper is particular, and (2) he likes his trophies. ***That is probably why he saves and displays them***.

- He is particular about who exactly will "donate" what parts of their body to him. *We know this because Trish volunteers herself to save her brother, but Creeper does not accept*. We also see him "smelling fear" in his victims that somehow tell him who is the best match. (This may be from the sequels.)
- We can be sure that the victims do not go willingly. Some are more successful at resisting than others -- making Creeper work harder to earn his body part. It's pretty apparent that Darry resisted quite a bit. At the end of the movie, we see Creeper playing his signature Jeepers Creepers song ("Where'd you get those eyes" -- see YouTube clip at bottom) *and then he stands behind his disemboweled trophy so that we can "see" where his eyes went*. Darry's remains have not been discarded; Darry is held in an upright position,  indicating what his fate will be. (See clip -- graphic)

**Caution: Very Graphic Clip**

The Jeepers Creepers song